# Facebook SDK permissions for tagging

Tags: facebook, react-native-fbsdk

I want to get my app approved by Facebook. My app is sharing posts on the users timeline. I requested the `user_friends` and `publish_actions` for this. Both got approved from Facebook.

I also requested the "Taggable Friends API", but this wasn't approved.

Do I even need this to publish content with a friend choosen via `user_friends`? Or is this somehow unrelated to what I'm doing? I only found OpenGraph examples with it and I'm not using OG in any place.

Comment: In normal posts made via API, you can only tag friends as being “with” the user, if you specify a place at the same time. (And both the user and the friend are supposed to actually be at that place at the time, otherwise you should not tag as “being with” in the first place.) Normal “mentioning” of users directly inside the message is not possible.

Comment: In the FBSDK both `place` and `userIds` are optional. I wanted to let the users publish "dedications" which are a text from a user, image from the app and tagged friend.

Comment: Doesn’t matter what properties might be optional in some SDK - the API makes place mandatory, if you also want to tag users. _“I wanted to let the users publish "dedications" which are a text from a user, image from the app and tagged friend”_ - AFAIK, not possible. You could “mention tag” people in custom OG stories, but those don’t exist any more.

Comment: I see, it was possible with the test users no problem. So I had the impression I just need this approved and can post. Is there any alternative for my use-case?

Comment: What exactly was possible using test users? Can you please show what exact request you are making, resp, what data you are sending?

Comment: This worked with a test user: `ShareApi.share({contentType: "photo", commonParameters: {peopleIds: ["..."]}, photos: [{imageUrl: "...", userGenerated: false}]})`

Comment: Ah, so you are actually uploading photos, that is something different than sharing posts ... Yes, for photo uploads, you can let users tag people that are in the photo with them. (But that is also a very strict requirement - the friend _has to_ be in the photo, otherwise you have no business tagging them in the first place.) As far as I know, this does not require any specific review of that particular feature. But you’ll be limited to tagging friends of the user that are also users of your app; the tokens taggable_friends returns don’t work in this context I think.

Comment: I'm using `user_friends` to get the userIds I'll tag later, isn't this independent from the `ShareApi`? Or will this list be filtered by the users that use my app?

Comment: Yes, of course, that will return friends that are users of your app only.

Comment: okay, thank you very much :)